# Adding additional information to a sequence using Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm

I'm building a recommender system using Keras LSTM. I have sequences of views from users of the form `[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3]` with `padding='pre'`. Each integer value (except 0) is an item id and the whole vector is a user's viewing history. I need to predict next item. A network:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 100, input_length=max_length-1))
model.add(LSTM(64))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
```

The vocab_size is a set of all unique items. There are about 2M items in total, but for now I'm using 100K.

I want to add additional information (item tags) to the network. There are 1M unique tags in total. What is the best way to pair an item and a set of tags using Keras? For example this won't work (I assume) because we won't know which item has which set of tags:

```
x_id_input = Input(shape=...)
x_id_emb = Embedding(id_vocab_size, 100)(x_id_input)
x_tag_input = Input(shape=...)
x_tag_emb = Embedding(tag_vocab_size, 100)(x_tag_input)
x = concatenate([x_id_emb, x_tag_emb])
x = LSTM(64)(x)
x_output = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Mode(inputs=[x_id_input, x_tag_input], outputs=x_output)
```

Comment: Why do you say that you won't know which item has which set of tags? You can pad them in exactly the same way, so to maintain the same position in the sequence

Comment: I see it this way: there are two users. The first one viewed items A, B, C, the second one viewed items C, D, A, C. Each item may have a set of tags from 0 to n, for example item A has x, y, z tags, item B p, q tags and so on. At the end it looks like this: `[[0, A, B, C], [C, D, A, C]]` (with zeros as padding). This is the first input (items). The second input (tags) is `[[x, y, z, p, q, ...], [i, j, ...]]`. If we concatenate them user-wise we will get a vector with a long sequence of items and tags with no way to tell which item has which tags.

Comment: Can't you make the tag vector a one-hot-encoded vector with N dimensions, where N is the number of possible tags? so you have a one-to-one relationship between items and tag vectors, and your tag input will have N as its third dimension.

Comment: I understand the idea, the problem is I have no idea how to implement it. Also one-hot representation should probably be in a sparse format. There are > 1M tags.

Comment: True about the sparsity. Then you can pre-train an embedding layer to learn the representation of your tags in a non-sparse way, use the corresponding weights for your tag embedding layer in the network setting trainable=False (https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html), passing a vector of tags for each timestamp, which will be converted to an embedded representation. Does that make sense?